# .Net Web API binding datetime with milli seconds

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

I have following controller action in C# web api project:

```cpp
        public object GetClients(DateTime? changedSinceDateTimeUtc = null)
        {
            // if date is not null, return all active clients, else 
            // return all client records changed since the date
        }
```

When the value is passed in format:

**yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:tttZ**

the value becomes null in the controller method.

If the format is

**yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.tttZ**

it translates correctly (note the difference is the separator between seconds and milli seconds).

E.g. http://192.168.1.24:7799/api/client?changedSinceDateTimeUtc=2020-07-21T03:50:16:234Z does not work

but http://192.168.1.24:7799/api/client?changedSinceDateTimeUtc=2020-07-21T03:50:16.234Z works as expected.

Funny part is that, on one of our client environments, it is the opposite. I.e. the ':' separator will translate to correct date time, while having '.' will translate to null DateTime? value.

Googling didn't gave me any lead unfortunately. The only option so far is ask the API clients not to send the ms component of the time stamp, but I would really need to have that for correct functionality.

I can perhaps declare the changedSinceDateTimeUtc as string and try to parse it manually. But I have lot of such endpoints that I don't wish to change (as it is a dirty workaround)

Has anyone come across such before and found a solution/workaround?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you going to call the GET method? I mean from browser or from front end ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the below change to the client application.

```
var dateString = dateObject.toISOString();
```

And pass the `dateString` as parameter.

Or you can use `toUTCString`method to the variable and pass to the API

Comment: This is an API open to 3rd party apps. I don't have control over them, those could be written in other languages than C#. I can only enforce a standard, and my concern is that in my end the standard differs between my dev PC and in one of our client's servers.